# Haskell language pragmas

Tags: haskell

What is the correct way to deduct what language pragmas are missing in case of an error?
Quite often I find myself with an error which I cant figure out for some time. After hours of distress, I realize/google/accidently find that a language pragma is missing and everything goes well after I insert the missing pragma.

It is not shown in the error, there is no clue like "try adding such and such pragma" or anything like that. I understand that the experienced haskellers just know it. But what about the beginners? Is there a way to instruct the compiler to give a clue?

For instance, I often get type errors with Snap framework unless I put {-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}. I just try it because I see it in other source files.
Is there a way to switch all the common pragmas on or at least to figure out what pragmas are needed in case of an error?

Comment: At least recent GHCs give a suggestion in most cases I've come across. Apart from that, if you know a pragma and it does something connected to the error message, try it out, e.g. `Ambiguous type variable`; hmm, maybe defaulting?; `ExtendedDefaultRules`. But if the compiler doesn't suggest anything, you have basically three options. 1. know (it's not so uncommon that one simply forgets to put the pragma in). 2. ask (#haskell, Stack Overflow, mailing lists, ...). 3. guess. Listed in descending order of nicety.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to avoid language extensions, so I tend to chase errors down as actual errors and change the way I'm doing things.

Comment: Also, if the error message is not helpful enough, and there is a chance that the compiler could already tell you the extension, why not file an enhancement but report at [the ghc bugtracker](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/) – preferably with a patch.

Answer (score 0):

GHC now suggests pragmas for most common issues. ExtendedDefaultRules is never suggested because it is never *necessary* -- rather, more explicit type signatures can obviate the need for it.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know much about Snap framework. If you use GHC, you can use language pragma as part of compiler directives: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/pragmas.html

Comment: This doesn't address the question. Also, that's not the latest GHC documentation.